# Want empty folder to return 404 instead of 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403

I use the following code in my httpd.conf file to block unwanted bots and visitors (e.g. hitting non existing wp-login pages):

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent BadBot GoAway=1
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=GoAway
```

This will give them a 403 Forbidden error. On my custom 403 page I save the IP's to a database for permanent blocking / disabling them from using contact forms etc.

This is working very well. However I noticed that some users are being blocked because they visited an empty folder. This is unwanted.

Using `Options -Indexes` I have prevented directory viewing but this will also output a 403 Forbidden error.

Question: How to serve and display a 404 error when visiting an empty folder instead of a 403?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you appear to have access to `httpd.conf` then you can do something like the following in a server config or virtualhost context:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule /. - [R=404]
```

Alternatively, near the top of your `.htaccess` file (since you've tagged your question `.htaccess`), include the following (this will also work in a *directory* context):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [R=404]
```

The purpose of the pattern `/.` (or `.`) is to prevent a 404 being served for the document root.

Depending on where you define your *custom* `ErrorDocument`, you may get a different 404 response for each method.

---

Alternatively, in your custom 403, perform the same check for the "BadBot" and only log the entry if there is a match. Or, only log the entry when the request does not map to a directory.